# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key when use Predicate Evaluate

Tags: swift

When i use predicate.evalute(with: ?) I have got a bug and App terminate and throw error

> Police i lert u[1005:286399] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[`< Police_i_lert_u.UserXML 0x11abf1d90 > valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key identifier.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x182b06364 0x181d4c528 0x182b0602c 0x1834ba434 0x183400e20 0x183441698 0x1834412d8 0x100f06c98 0x100f06dc4 0x182ae3f40 0x100f06374 0x100f07218 0x18c01c6b4 0x18c01c634 0x18c0071dc 0x18c01bf28 0x18c677610 0x18c672bc0 0x18c6726a4 0x18c671800 0x18c016f44 0x18bfe7f64 0x18c93d31c 0x18c93f8a8 0x18c9387c0 0x182aae97c 0x182aae8fc 0x182aae184 0x182aabd5c 0x1829cbe58 0x184878f84 0x18c04b67c 0x100f3dc3c 0x1824e856c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

my code:

```
@objc func addButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    alertController.showHUDProgress(message: nil, vc: self)

    let friendId = String(format: "%ld", String(sender.tag))
    let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "identifier ==[c] %@", friendId)
    let index = users.indexOfObject(passingTest: { (object, idx, stop) -> Bool in
        return predicate.evaluate(with: object)
    })

    if index != NSNotFound {
        weak var weakSelf = self
        friendModel.setCompletionBlock(success: { (object) -> Void in
            weakSelf?.addFriendDidSuccess(index: index)
        }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
            weakSelf?.addFriendDidFailure(error: error ?? nil)
        })
    }
    else {
        alertController.hideHUDProgress(vc: self)

        var indexMessage: String!

        if isSet {
            if language == "TH" {
                indexMessage = "ไม่พบผู้ใช้"
            }
            else {
                indexMessage = "Index User not found"
            }
        }

        alertController.alertMessage(message: indexMessage, title: nil, vc: self, isCancel: false)
    }
}
```

please help me fix my problem.

thank you.

Comment: What does `users` contain? And why do you use that ugly *objective-c-ish* code (`indexOfObject(passingTest`)?

Comment: uses contains Class Value. I migrated code old project

Comment: Add the code of Class which `users` array contains.

Comment: At least you have to add `@objc` also to the property in the class. And I recommend to use native `if let index = users.index(where: {$0.identifier.compare(friendId, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame }) {` and get rid of the predicate.

Comment: I will tired thank you.