# NSPredicate not working in Swift Playground (signal SIGABRT)

Tags: swift, nspredicate, swift-playground

I created a Swift Playground to test some NSPredicate stuff. But it does not run. Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

class Person: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let married: Bool
    
    init(name: String, age: Int, married: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.married = married
    }
}

let p1 = Person(name: "Person 1", age: 32, married: true)
let p2 = Person(name: "Person 2", age: 61, married: true)
let p3 = Person(name: "Person 3", age: 45, married: false)

let ppl: NSArray = [p1, p2, p3]

let filter_name1 = NSPredicate(format: "name = 'Person 1'")
ppl.filtered(using: filter_name1)
```

When running I get the error (for the last line):

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

And in the log of the Playground I see:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: A tip, check on a macOS/iOS app when you have this kind of error, you'll get more infos, like: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Person 0x102a05650> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559542/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-when-use-predicate-eval add `@objc`before `let name: String`. But, do you really need to use a `NSArray`?, not Swift `filter()`?

Comment: I don't need a NSArray by default, but I need to test some NSPredicate stuff, therefor I used NSArray. Is this also possible with the default filter? I think no.

Comment: the @objc solved the issue. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Rob Napier gives a better and more explained answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/31323718/1801544 . Update his anwer ;)